# Como verificar o domínio a que o utilizador está

Tags: php

Bom a minha pergunta é a seguinte:

Eu tenho vários domínios que apontam todos para o mesmo local no meu site:

www.exemplo1.com
www.exemplo2.com
www.exemplo3.com

Como faço para verificar com PHP, qual o domínio que o utilizador está a usar para navegar no meu site?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável global `$_SERVER` contém as informações que necessita.

O domínio corrente pode ser obtido no índice `HTTP_HOST` ou `SERVER_NAME`.

Note que são dados que dependem das configurações do ambiente, ou seja, as configuraões do Sistema Operacional e principalmente do servidor de páginas WEB (apache, iis, nginx, etc).

Portanto, não confie plenamente nessas variáveis. Sempre verifique a integridade quando trocar de ambiente.

Sem mais delongas, um exemplo de como obter o que deseja:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

ou

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Note também que `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` pode retornar o número da porta concatenado ao nome do host.

Exemplo `localhost:81`

Verifique também outros índices do array `$_SERVER`:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
```

Por via das dúvidas, apenas faça um `print_r($_SERVER)` e veja onde aparece o nome do host.

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Lembrando que o nome do host é independente do DNS, por isso, em determinadas situações o nome do host pode retornar algo que não tem nada a ver com o nome do domínio DNS.

Concluindo, não confie plenamente nesses dados.

O mais correto é que o servidor de hospedagem tenha como estrutura padrão o nome do domínio definido também como o nome do virtual host. Mas muitos servidores, principalmente compartilhados, não adotam essa regra, podendo apresentar nomes que não tem relação com o domínio DNS.